# A lot of views in ViewController

Tags: ios, view, viewcontroller

Is it good to make a lot of views in single ViewController?
Views will be at fullscreen, always will be showed just one view (rest hidden) with different images, labels, etc.
or is it better to make a lot of ViewControllers? It must be like one view per one page. What is the best way to make 100 different views?

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to make? Do you want an app with lot of pages that you can exlpore?

Comment: That's right, but I think making a lot of ViewControllers is a bad idea? I just want to make few buttons, images and textfields per page.

Comment: Making a 100 views at once and hiding/showing them is even worse. It will take a lot of memory footprint (RAM) of device. It is generally not advisable.

Comment: Ok, thank you. What will be the best way to make something like that?

Comment: Are the views looking the same way or have the views different layouts?

Comment: Sometimes different layouts.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keeping a 100 views in memory is going to cost you a lot of RAM in your device. It is generally not advisable. My advise for you is to look into different [iOS architecture patterns](https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/ios-architecture-patterns-ecba4c38de52#.at8yyjehz) and decide which one is better by yourself depending up on your application's logic.

Comment: Thank you for help!